# Sorting Backbone.Collection using date and priority

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Ok so, I have a collection filled with objects of a certain model, this model contains a date and a priority, I want it to be sorted by date, then by the priority, I currently have it implemented this way:

```
App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Task,
comparator: function(model) 
{
  return model.get("date") + model.get("priority");
}
});
```

This is my output:

```
Get to the party  Edit Delete 1 Fri Feb 1
Get to the party  Edit Delete 2 Mon Jan 28
Go to the store  Edit Delete 4 Mon Jan 28
Go to the mall  Edit Delete 3 Tue Jan 29
Get to the party  Edit Delete 3 Tue Jan 29
Get to the party  Edit Delete 5 Tue Jan 29
Get to the party  Edit Delete 2 Wed Jan 30
Get to work  Edit Delete 5 Wed Jan 30
```

I want earlier dates to be on top at all times so the february date should be last, how could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is stored in your `date` property?

Comment: Example: date: "Wed Jan 30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
comparator: function(model1, model2) {
    return (model1.get("date") + model1.get("priority")) -
        (model2.get("date") + model2.get("priority"));
}
```

[Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) claims, that returned value should be -1, 0 or 1, but that wasn't mandatory earlier and any value could do the trick.

**EDIT**

```
comparator: function(model1, model2) {
    var comp = (model1.get("date") + model1.get("priority")) -
        (model2.get("date") + model2.get("priority"));
    if (comp < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (comp > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now code precisely follows specification mentioned. If this didn't solve the problem, then the problem is not in comparator.

**EDIT**

Silly me. I assumed that you are storing a unix time in `date`, but apparently you don't. Subtracting strings gives NaN, so no sorting is made indeed. So all you need to do now is to cast `date` to unix time format (or at least something similar), then it should be working.

Comment: Hmmm, Im not sure I follow, where would the second model come from?

Comment: `comparator` is called internally in `sort` function, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I tried implementing this 


`App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: App.Models.Task,
 comparator: function(model1, model2) 
 {
   return (model1.get("date") + model1.get("priority"))-(model2.get("date")+model2.get("priority"));
 }
});`


The result was no sorting was made.

Comment: It still resulted in no sorting made at all, maybe its because of the way im implementing it? 

I was thinking of first using underscore.js's _.groupBy to separate them using the dates and then using sort on them but im not sure how to achieve this...


Thanks for all your help